# ZPL: how to set max width of a "text field"

Tags: zpl

Given a list of small strings (1 to 3 words each), I would like to print them in 2 columns using ZPL for Zebra Printers. For example, if the list is `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]`, I would like my label to look like this:

```
A      B
C      D
E
```

However, if strings are a little bit longer, I would like to be able to truncate them so that columns don't overlap. For example, if the list is `["string 1", "string 2", "long string 3", "string 4", "string 5"]`, the label should look like this:

```
string 1  string 2
long str  string 4
string 5
```

I see 2 possible approaches to this:
1) Using some ZPL command that I have not been able to find yet
2) Calculating the width of the strings in pixels. In this case I would need to know what is the font used by ZPL.

I'm using this command for text printing:

```
^A0,N,30,30
^FDtext^FS
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like ^TB is the solution:

```
^A0N,30,30
^TBN,250,29
^FDtext should go here^FS
```